# Custom second right click menu always

Tags: linux, desktop, context-menu, right-click, mouse-click

I want a second right click menu to always appear with my own custom options and commands.

I'm on Lubuntu linux right now with LXQt and I don't think that can be easily changed. I'm not sure how that might affect things.

My hope is there is an easy way to hook a Python script up to the right-click or some similar idea.

[image: CustomSecondRightClickMenuAlways.png]